# Laptop keyboard repeats keystrokes/characters at random

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

My laptop keyboard occasionally interprets a single keystroke as three keystrokes. This happens anywhere from 10-100 times/day in all programs and I can't isolate any pattern or cause. It definitely affects every alphanumeric key and the space bar. I can't be certain whether it affects other keys. The events do seem to occur in groups as in the example below but this might just be me noticing patterns that aren't there.

> The quiiiccck brown fox jjjumps over the lazy dogs.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430. A while ago I swapped the "Fn" and "Ctrl" keys in the BIOS. I'm also running TPFanControl most of the time because the fan noise is ridiculous otherwise. Due to the random nature of the problem I haven't conclusively proven that these aren't the causes. I have run virus scanners, etc. and found nothing. I haven't been able to try an external keyboard.

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT: I do intend to send it back if I can't resolve it myself but sending it back is a last resort as I need it for school and work and can't really afford to be without it for any length of time. Hopefully it is just a driver issue or something.

Comment: Can you connect a USB keyboard and see if issue remains?  That would isolate the issue to software or hardware perhaps.

Comment: Yeah - don't have a spare keyboard at the moment but that's my next step when I get a chance.

Comment: Dirt making the contacts in the keyboard stick? Just a random(ish) guess...

Comment: What environment is this? Everything updated? Check you don't have any "practical joke" malware installed.

Comment: T430 is rather new, check if the warranty is valid